# objective c, notify other threads

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous

My task is to download content, parse it, save in database and update UI after completion (or notify user about error). This will be used in different parts of application, so I want to extract this code to separate class and use as an asynchronous facade. I use NSURLConnection to handle network tasks. NSURLConnection calls my callbacks in separate thread. But my UI code should run in main thread. I could store set of blocks to call and invoke them from main thread with dispatch_async, but it means that this main thread will be hardcoded. It looks for me that I want to reinvent the wheel and there should be some mechanism used in objective c to communicate between threads, but I can't find it. Basically I want:

Receivers subscribe to receive messages with given identifier and specifying thread where notifications should be dispatched.

Sender sends message identifier and some attached data.

All subscribed receivers get this message in the threads they specified.

Or is there is another pattern appropriate for my task?

Comment: Instead subscribing, what is the problem with a block submitting the next step as another block in whatever queue, then updating the UI from the last block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to communicate between objects running on different thread.And post notification from different thread.

[See Apple NSNotificationCenter Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To update UI Elements on Main Thread use 
`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(somefunction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`